# Capistrano deploy failing with scp: /tmp/<project_name>/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied

Tags: git, deployment, ssh, capistrano

I'm tearing my hair out here. I assume the deploy user, in this case `www-data`, doesn't have sufficient privileges make the necessary directory. Or is this an SSH related problem?

I'm using Capistrano 3.5 to deploy onto Ubuntu 15.10.

Here's the full trace

```
00:00 git:wrapper
      01 mkdir -p /tmp/project_name/
    ✔ 01 www-data@88.xxx.xxx.xxxx
(Backtrace restricted to imported tasks)
cap aborted!
scp: /tmp/project_name/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied

Tasks: TOP => git:check => git:wrapper
(See full trace by running task with --trace)
The deploy has failed with an error: scp: /tmp/project_name/git-ssh.sh: Permission denied

** DEPLOY FAILED
** Refer to log/capistrano.log for details. Here are the last 20 lines:  

  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO START 2016-05-18 17:34:33 +0100 cap production deploy
  INFO ---------------------------------------------------------------------------
  INFO [a283be11] Running /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/project_name/ as www-data@88.xxx.xxx.xx
 DEBUG [a283be11] Command: /usr/bin/env mkdir -p /tmp/project_name/
  INFO [a283be11] Finished in 2.160 seconds with exit status 0 (successful).
 DEBUG Uploading /tmp/project_name/git-ssh.sh 0.0%
```

### Edit for Kenster

on server ran

```
ls -lR /tmp/<project_name>
```

output

```
/tmp/<project-name>:
total 4
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 93 May 17 22:21 git-ssh.sh
```

Comment: @Kenster i think i see, what next

Comment: i fixed it... chown www-data /tmp/project_name/git-ssh.sh.... I'll let you answer thought and dem points!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the end I just had to set the permissions for my deploy user 'www-data' on the git-ssh.sh file by running

```
   chown www-data /tmp/project_name/git-ssh.sh
```

Answer (score 0):

Wow, I'm super late with this, but I just ran into the same issue, working on migrating some legacy code from cap 2 to cap 3!

Because the folder is in the `/tmp` directory a restart would likely clear your issue. But looking at the issue further, changing file ownership is a solution, but simply deleting the folder I think is possibly a better solution. I only say this as the `/tmp` folder is supposed to be treated as temporary, and can be cleared by the host on restart. Not knowing the what the files are for, or what the ideal permissions and ownership is supposed to be, just delete the file!

If you're like me, you're doing a ton of deploys, running into issues with each deploy, as you try to figure out all of your cap tasks. At some point, I'd bet we both updated our deploy user, but only after we had tried deploying with the wrong user set. This is why we have the permissions issue.